# fs.unlink delete the files but also throw no such file or directory error

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, async.js

I try to delete some local files using fs.unlink after I upload them in s3 bucket, it will delete the files, but also throw no such file or directory error.

I run this command inside the `drain callback` of a [async queue](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue) , based on the async documentation, drain is called when the last item from the queue has returned, but in my case it seems it run twice, because when I run I can see my console log `console.log('Completed upload in', delta, 'seconds')` twice, once it completed in 0.001 seconds and the second one after all files uploaded to s3 bucket which takes almost 250 seconds, and here I also get error for my unlink which says no such file or directory error.  :

```
const q = async.queue((task, callback) => {
    s3.upload(params, options, callback)
}

q.drain = function () { // It seems this method run twice!
    var delta = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000
    console.log('Completed upload in', delta, 'seconds')
    fs.unlink(`./${task.src}`, (err) => {
      if (err) console.log("ERROR", err)
          console.log(`successfully deleted ${task.src}`)
    })
    return true
}
q.push(fileNamesReformat)
```

Comment: Try using `async.series`. Create the series dynamically like you are pushing the `fileNamesReformat` then execute the series. The reason I feel that it is calling twice is that because the operation for `q` completes sooner than the `push` operation. So, the system detect an empty queue and triggers the `drain` and when the remaining item is pushed it process it and `drain` it. I also faced similar issue just few days ago and I switched into `async.series`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal this code is pat of a bigger module which needs to run in parallel, so I can't use series.

Comment: It is really difficult to figure out why this is happening. But this happens as it had already happened to me. And the reason for me was that what I mentioned above. You can further debug your code to get better insights.